# Handler mapping on IIS / OWIN /Nancy for a CSV file

Tags: iis, csv, handler-mappings

I've an issue with IIS and OWIN/Nancy, here is the setup of our server :

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- IIS 8.5
- OWIN with Nancy (middleware)
- ASP.NET 4.5
- Application developed in F#.

I want to download a .csv file with an URL like this :

https://www.myserver.com/Reports/Current/2014-11-10.csv

This file must be handled by Nancy and not by IIS.

So I think that I need to add a handler mapping to OWIN/nancy on IIS like this :

```
 <handlers>
      <add name="CSV files" path="/Reports/Current/*.csv" verb="GET" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler" resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
 </handlers>
```

But it still doesn't work, I've always a 404 error when I'm trying to download this CSV file.

Does anyone have an idea to help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not to add a "CSV" handler, but to configure the `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0` script map to handle paths with extensions. You can do this by changing the path from `*.` to `*`. This will pass all requests to Nancy (in your case), irrespective of whether they have an extension.